# java process dies in f1 micro

Tags: tomcat, google-compute-engine

I tried to start one Tomcat instance with two applications in google compute engine. I selected f1.micro since I expect very light traffic for my instance since it is a demo application at very early stage. However, tomcat process is killed somehow during startup. If I select g1-small, it is no problem. I know f1-micro is shared GCPU. But at least I should be able to start a process.

I check the document and could not find any answer or hint.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

It is our of memory issue. I saw this in /var/log/message
 Out of memory: Kill process 2454 (java) score 646 or sacrifice child.
f1-micro has only 0.6G memory.

Answer (score 0):

You might try reducing the heap size requested by java using the -Xmx and -Xms flags.  In particular, as you noted, the f1-micro has only 600MB of RAM, so you'll want to either [enable swap](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/) (which may lead to bad performance if it's used -- Java's GC is likely to touch much of the memory it's allocated before re-using earlier bits), or reduce the RAM footprint of your java app.  I'd expect that you'd probably lose at least 200MB of RAM to OS+java overhead, so I'd start with `-Xms256m -Xmx256m` and see how your app performs.

Comment: reduce heapsize is not an option for me. My app needs more RAM. I switched to Amazon t2.micro. They are almost the same price. But t2.micro performs much better.